# Get values based on newly inserted value using SQL

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to make filtration on a column after selecting a specific value of another column in the same table, I tried to use `@...` special character followed by the column's name to get the address of this value.

My SQL statement is like the following :

```
SELECT ATTRIBUTE FROM TABLE WHERE FIELD = '@FIELDNAME';
```

If I used a specific value instead of `@FIELDNAME`, it will work properly but it will be static but I need it to be dynamic based on the selected value.

Comment: Why not use an on insert/update trigger?

Comment: The software that I am using sql in allows only few basic keywords for sqlQuery and CREATE TRIGGER is one of the not allowed keywords, so if there is any other solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create another table which will have the list of values that are in the FIELDNAME and give each record a unique id ,then retrieve the value depending on what you have selected by the name of the new table's field preceded by '@...'

I don't know if that what are you looking for, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

If no triggers are allowed, do you have any `date/time` column in the table? Is it possible to have that extra column anyway to see the time of a newly inserted row?

You may have to check the lastest row entered, save its `field` value into a variable. Then do the `select` based on the variable value.

Based on the *vague* last row id you could try the following (it's not pretty). But again, if you have date/time that's more accurate.

```
select attribute from table 
where field = (select field from table 
where rowid =(select max(rowid) from table))
;
```

**upate**
Do you have the priviledge to set up your insert command as below:

```
insert into table (id, col1, col2,...) values (1,'something', 'something',...)
returning id into variable; -- you may either save field or id depending on your table
```

Then you may use this `variable` to select the records you want.

Comment: That will not help because date/time column in this table could be inserted previously and it could be an old date, and there is no log table that shows the latest values entered.

Comment: If not `rowid`, you gotta have something that increases or decreases as the new row inserted...can you point that out? or is your table a *something* without any referential integrity and sequencing/indexing...? ;)

Comment: It's not a new row, it's already existed and it will be updated when the other field value is changed, but there is no index or something else shows that it's updated recently. anyway thanks for you effort :)